Does SystemVerilog have a log package that allows fine control over log messages?
VHDL has OSVVM and VUnit that provide log packages. One can create different levels for log messages by assigning numerical values with names. Higher value means message is more important. Then a filter setting is specified. Log messages that have a level that is less than filter setting numerical value are ignored and not printed into the transcript but those that have equal or greater value are printed into the transcript. This gives fine control over what messages are printed by the testbench when the test is run.
Now my question is, does this feature exist in some way for SystemVerilog as well?

SystemVerilog has the UVM class library.  A common way to control log messages is to use the `uvm_info macro:
`uvm_info("TRANS", "some message", UVM_MEDIUM)

The verbosity is controlled by the 3rd argument.
There are examples of UVM code on EDA Playground.
It is possible to only use the logging feature of UVM, if desired.
